# Python MySQLdb unexpected behaviour (?)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I want to ensure that SQL-injection isn't possible, but I'm experiencing weird behaviour with this snippet. My user-input is in "field" and "name"; I've also written a snipped to allow only valid values for "field", thus preventing injection, but there should be a better way?

Also, the first query returns the expected results, the second returns (('Beschreibung',),) and the third also works as expected. Why is that, what am I doing wrong in #2? Is there an other, recommended way in python to prevent SQL-injection?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(db="cmdb", user="root", passwd="test", host="127.0.0.1")
cur=db.cursor()

field="Beschreibung"
name="testhost"

sql="SELECT %s FROM cmdb WHERE Name=\"%s\"" % (field, name,)
cur.execute(sql)
data=cur.fetchall()
print data

sql='SELECT %s FROM cmdb WHERE Name=%s'
cur.execute(sql, (field,name) )
data=cur.fetchall()
print data

sql='SELECT * FROM cmdb WHERE Name=%s'
cur.execute(sql, (name,) )
data=cur.fetchall()
print data
```

DB-scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE cmdb (Name varchar(128),BSI varchar(128),Projekt varchar(128),Typ varchar(128),Beschreibung varchar(128),Betriebssystem varchar(128),Version varchar(128),Level varchar(128),Standort varchar(128),Status varchar(128),HE varchar(128),Position varchar(128),Seite varchar(128),Hersteller varchar(128),Modell varchar(128),CPU varchar(128),NrCPUs varchar(128),CoresjeCPU varchar(128),RAM varchar(128),Festplatten varchar(128),Besonderheiten varchar(128),IPWAN varchar(128),Teilnetz varchar(128),primaryIP varchar(128),weitereIPs varchar(128),NagiosGruppen varchar(128),Dependson varchar(128),Feed varchar(128),Updategruppe varchar(128),NRBuchhaltung varchar(128),IPMI varchar(128),Admin varchar(128),Eingebaut\nDurch varchar(128),Benutzer varchar(128),Notiz varchar(128),Haendler varchar(128)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;ALTER TABLE cmdb ADD UNIQUE KEY hostname (Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried execute "cur.execute(sql, (field,name,) )" ?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change anything.